# wp_query: implicit paging? I get less posts that I should

Tags: wp-query

A newbe wp_query question:
I set a wp_query as follows, but instead of 17 posts I only get the first 10 posts from the selected Category with ID=5.
Is there an implicit paging directive on the results?

```
    $myPosts = new WP_Query(); 
    $args_posts = array('cat' => 5);
    $myPosts->query($args_posts);           
    while ($myPosts->have_posts()) : $myPosts->the_post();          
            ?>              
            <div class="post">                  
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="cover"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark,nofollow" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $img ?>&amp;h=80&amp;w=120&amp;zc=1" width="120" height="80" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(240, __('read more &raquo;')); ?></p>              
            </div>              
            <?php endwhile;             
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: I found the argument $query = new WP_Quer('nopaging=true');
but I am not sure it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the pages instead, you should add
`posts_per_page'=>-1` to your query

You can have a look at the Wordpress Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query